# Proof of inequality with local martingale and stopping time..

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, expectation, local-martingales

Let $M$ be continuous local martingale starting from zero. For $a>0$, let $\tau_a=\inf \left\{t \ge 0: |M_t|>a \right\}$. Show that for every $t \ge 0$ we have:
$a^2\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\le t)\le\mathbb{E}<M>_{\tau_a \wedge t}$

So I have few problems with this task, I count on your help. What I've thought:
the condition $\left\{ \tau_a \le t \right\}$ is equal to : $\left\{ \tau_a \le t \right\}=\left\{ \sup\limits_{s\le t} |M_s| \ge a \right\}=\left\{ \sup\limits_{s\ge 0} |M_s^{\tau_a \wedge t}| \ge a \right\}$.
What is more if I know that $M^{\tau_a \wedge t}$ was a martingale I could use martingale inequality, and got:
$a^2\mathbb{P}(\sup\limits_{s\ge 0} |M_s^{\tau_a \wedge t}| \ge a)\le \sup\limits_{s\ge 0}\mathbb{E}(|M_s^{\tau_a \wedge t}|^2)$.

My problem is:

1. How to show that $M^{\tau_a \wedge t}$ is a martingale?
   (I know that it is enough to say that it is local martingale and it is bounded, but Im not sure if it is true that it is bounded..)
2. How do I know the thesis of the problem using above inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It follows from the continuity of the sample paths and the definition of $\tau_a$ that $|M_{t \wedge \tau_a}| \leq a$ for all $t \geq 0$. This means that $M^{\tau_a}$ is, indeed, a bounded process. Moreover, the optional stopping theorem implies that it is a local martingale.
2. By the definition of the quadratic variation, we know that $(N_s^2 - \langle N \rangle_s)_{s \geq 0}$ is a martingale for any (continuous) square-integrable martingale $(N_s)_{s \geq 0}$. This implies, in particular, $$\mathbb{E}(N_s^2) = \mathbb{E}(\langle N \rangle_s)$$ for all $s \geq 0$. Use this identity with $N_s := M_s^{\tau_a \wedge t}$ and the fact that $s \mapsto \langle M^{\tau_a \wedge t} \rangle_s$ is non-decreasing.